# Need for alternative/addition to "Off topic"

Tags: discussion

I'm fairly new here, but I've seen a bunch of questions closed for being "off-topic"

When I click on the off topic link, the *only* thing that ever seems to apply would be that the question belongs in English Language Learners.

In this case, would it not be better for moderators to just move it to ell?

If not, then possibly a better tag that off-topic, perhaps a cluster of tags to point at the specific reason why it's off topic.

I'm part of a bunch of SE groups. I've seldom been confused as to closed questions.

Comment: Note that there are two close reasons that mention ELL. One actually does move the Q to that site, so I think you’re not asking about that one. The other mentions ELL among other things, and is also our most common close reason, ie. “if you’d checked a dictionary/thesaurus/ google before asking, you wouldn’t have had to ask”. ELL is mentioned there as maybe a better site for *future* questions (but this Q doesn’t merit moving there as is). As for “more specific reasons”: closure on SE doesn’t work like that. The close reasons are fixed: any additional color must be given in comments, it at all

Comment: Another issue is the general directive not to migrate poor questions. If a question can be improved and migrated, great -- and every user regardless of rep is in a position to help with that. If a poor question cannot be improved, it shouldn't be migrated.

Comment: Note that 'closure reasons' as presented on closure are rarely the whole story. Five different CV reasons may have contributed (and sometimes all will be valid), but not all will be mentioned (unless matters have recently changed). // If CVers had always to give reasons in a comment, all would become more open and often more clear, but fewer questions that need closing would _get_ closed. Policing is a chore and invites flak.

Comment: It needs to be clear why a question is a poor question.  Otherwise we don't learn.

Comment: @SherwoodBotsford It is very common (but not guaranteed) that someone will have commented with constructive criticism of the question. That’s where the feedback is. But bear in mind that the OP is not the only beneficiary of such curation activities, and teaching OP is not the only goal. Curation is also intended to create and maintain a long-lasting high-quality library for millions of web visitors, now and in the future. Poor quality questions inhibit that goal, and removing them furthers it. By far, the overwhelming majority of such Qs are asked by users better served by ELL.